# Simple vectors question with hexagon

Tags: vectors

[image]

I’m trying  to understand vectors, and I have got part 1, but how would you express EF, is that also just 6b-6a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a regular hexagon, the vector from $E$ to $F$ is the same as the vector from $O$ to $A$. So we have $\overrightarrow{EF}= 6a$.